# Denseness of normal and non-normal numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to prove that normal numbers are dense ? I have read in a book that this set has full measure. so dense. Then how to argue for the no-normal numbers. They also turn out to be dense. How to argue for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminating decimals are all non-normal and they are easily seen to be dense. Furthermore, if you believe in the existence of at least one normal number $x$, then any terminating decimal leads to a normal number by appending the digits of the fractional part of $x$ onto the terminating decimal. Thus, the normal numbers are dense.